# How to remove the space after \hbox and \vbox in PlainTeX?

Tags: plain-tex, eplain

I'm trying to remove the space after `\hbox` or `\vbox`.

## Example:

```
\def\w#1{%
    \vbox{%
        \hbox to #1{%
            \vrule width 1pt
            \kern -1pt
            \vbox to #1 {%
                \hrule width #1 height 1pt
                \vfil
                \hrule width #1 height 1pt
            }%  
            \vrule width 1pt
            \kern -1pt
        }%  
    }%  
}

\vrule width 1pt height 3cm \w{1cm} \vrule width 1pt height 3cm
```

[image: result]

I'm trying to get rid of the space between `\w` and `\vrule`.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I get no space with your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing two aspects of TeX.

### First pass: *tokenization*

Your input `\vrule width 1pt height 3cm \w{1cm} \vrule` is transformed into the following sequence of tokens

```
\vrule•w•i•d•t•h•⍽•1•p•t•⍽•h•e•i•g•h•t•⍽•3•c•m•⍽•\w•{•1•c•m•}•⍽•\vrule
```

*Note*: `•` separates tokens from one another, `⍽` denotes a space token.

Note there's no space token after `\vrule`.

### Second pass: *command processing and expansion*

The first token is a primitive that can be followed by a sequence of keywords and values; the five tokens `w•i•d•t•h` are recognized as a keyword and TeX looks for a dimension, finding `⍽•1•p•t` where the space is ignored by rule in this case as part of the search for ⟨optional signs⟩. The space after a dimension specification is also ignored by rule.

Similarly for `•h•e•i•g•h•t•⍽•3•c•m•⍽`.

Now TeX comes to `\w` which is a one argument macro; since the following token is `{`, TeX looks for the matching `}` brace and passes the argument `1•c•m` to the expansion processor: the replacement text is inserted, with `#1` replaced by `1•c•m`.

Note that at this moment, the processing of `\vrule` has not yet finished. It finishes as soon as TeX restarts examining tokens, in this case it finds `\vbox` which cannot be part of the specifications for `\vrule`, so the command is executed and the tokens up to `\vbox` discarded.

Now the contents of the `\vbox` is determined (long story here, I'll gloss over it), ending at `}`. The `\vbox` is constructed, added to the horizontal list being processed and the tokens discarded. Next comes a space token, which is passed to the horizontal list. Then TeX finds `\vrule` and goes on as before.

### Comments

There is a big difference between “spaces ignored after control sequences” during tokenization and “space tokens ignored during command processing”. In the first case the space never reaches the *mouth* of TeX (more technically, it doesn't generate any token).

Some space tokens can happen to be ignored during command processing: spaces preceding a keyword, spaces preceding a dimension specification, a space following a constant (when TeX is looking for a number) and several other cases.

A very important case when space tokens are ignored is when TeX is looking for *undelimited arguments* to a macro.

If you do `\def\macro#1#2{-#1-#2-}`, then the calls

```
\macro{a}{b}
\macro{a} {b}
\macro ab
\macro a b
```

are completely equivalent. But this is because `\macro` is defined to have *two* undelimited arguments. A space token after the second argument is not ignored.

In your case `\w` has a single argument, so the space after `\w{3cm}` is not ignored.

If you don't want it, just don't type it:

```
\vrule width 1pt height 3cm \w{1cm}\vrule
```

### Final comments

“Space token” in the text above means “explicit space token”, that is a character token with category code 10.

Do you need to be aware of all the quirks above? No, if you're a simple user. If you want to program TeX, you should take care of these details. For instance,

```
\vbox{
  abc
}
```

and `\vbox{abc}` will produce the same results. To the contrary,

```
\hbox{
  abc
}
```

wouldn't. Why? The long versions get tokenized as

```
\vbox•{•⍽•a•b•c•}
```

and

```
\hbox•{•⍽•a•b•c•}
```

so they look pretty similar, don't they? Well, yes and no. In the `\vbox` case, the first space token is encountered in vertical mode and it does nothing (it *doesn't* get ignored, though); the second space token actually generates a space, which is removed because of the implicit `\par` added when the `\vbox` ends.

In the `\hbox` case, the two space tokens are found in horizontal mode and both generate a glue node in the horizontal list.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error. It's the whitespace after `\w{1cm}`. TeX ignores doesn't ignore spaces after macro that has parameters in the `{}` form.
Corected version:

```
\vrule width 1pt height 3cm \w{1cm}\vrule width 1pt height 3cm
```

Comment: You edited the code after my comment.